# IdentityServer 3: How to validate the ClaimsIdentity in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I use the IdentityServer 3 with the ResourceOwner Flow.
It seems to work. I can see in fiddler the token is accessed and validated by my WebAPI.

```
     app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
     {
        Authority = "http://server/IdentityServer/",
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "MyFramework" },
        SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
        DelayLoadMetadata = true
     });
```

If I configure:
ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint
There is an extra request.
With ValidationMode.Local there is not. (This is good because IdentityServer is embedded in the WebAPI).

But if I use ValidationMode.Local, there are TWO requests to the IdentityServer.
http://server/IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration
http://server/IdentityServer/.well-known/jwks

Why is this reccessary? The IdentityServer is embedded and this information is accessible in-memory. Even if the setting is "ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint" this two calls do not appear.

But back to my primary question:
How can I validate the ClaimsIdentity in my WebAPI?
I have an "AuthenticationHandler" (ASP.NET-DelegatingHandler) that handles the validation for my old basic-authentication.

I figured out I can use the HttpContext.Current.User to access the IPrincipal.
Now I check it is of the type "ClaimsIdentity" and the Identity.IsAuthenticated==true.

Is this a correct approach?
And how can I check the User-ID?

On the server-side the ID of the user is put in the "sub"-claim (aka 'Subject').
Do I have to access this specific property to check which user is logged in?

I could access it like this:
ClaimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("sub"));

BUT only with the setting "ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint".
Then the AuthenticationType of the IPrincipal is "Bearer" and the 'sub'-claim is present.

With the setting "ValidationMode.Local" the AuthenticationType is "JWT" and the claim is not present.

Why does the ValidationMode changes the IPrincipal? Do I have to check this for different cases?